# Why isn't arange defined?

Tags: python

I have no programming experience and am learning Python for a class. I'm going through conditionals now and have a problem that I'm not understanding the cause of.

I'm basically just trying to let someone plot x^2 within a desired interval of x with the restriction that x isn't negative. If the user inputs a negative input, they'll get a message saying it's not allowed. Otherwise, x vs. x^2 should be plotted.

```
N = input('Enter upper limit of x:');
if N < 0:
    print "Negative input isn't allowed."
else:
    x = arange(N)
    y = x*x
    plot(x,y)
```

The above gives me the error:

```
NameError: name 'arange' is not defined
```

Which I don't understand because `arange()` is normally defined from my (very little) understanding.

Comment: `from numpy import *`?

Comment: You have a typo in the question title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you been exposed to `python` through the `ipython` interactive shell? with `ipython` it is still possible to use the deprecated command line switch `-pylab` that exposes to the user the `matplotlib` interactive commands from the `matplotlib.pyplot` module and all the `numpy` library.

When you bring these habits in writing your first python program you will find that things are more complicated...

You have essentially two solutions, the first one is

```
from pylab import *
...
```

that allows you to call unqualified function names like `arange` and `plot` from your script and, second one

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# ...
x = np.arange(N)
# ...
plt.plot(x, x*x)
```

even if the second possibility is more verbose than the first, it is the recommended avenue: unqualified imports are considered bad practice because they pollute the namespace of your script, and this is particularly true with large modules like `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy` that defines hundreds of names!

Re the names used for the imports, that is `np` and `plt`, these choices are a sort of best practice agreement that you'd be wise to adopt, as you'll find on the net and on SO 1000's of examples that use exactly these names to access the plotting and numerical libraries.

To summarize, using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

is a so common idiom that it is what I advice you to do.

Answer (score 8):

Python has a lot of built in commands.  However, `arange` and `plot` are not some of them.  These are provided by `numpy` and `matplotlib`.

To get your code to work, you could add:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import *
```

at the top of your code.  This isn't the recommended way though.  It's better to do:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
```

and then when you call their functions

```
x=numpy.arange(N)
```

and

```
matplotlib.plot(x,y)
```

The reason that this is recommended is sometimes you may have other modules that have the same function names.

A (very) slightly more advanced version that is even better is like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.arange(N)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

`np` is a standard abbreviation for `numpy` and `plt` is a standard abbreviation of `matplotlib.pyplot` (which is where the command `plot` is actually defined).  These are the standard abbreviations, and importing just part of `matplotlib` is good for reducing overhead.

You should read up on what a numpy array is versus a usual python list.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I'll look up the differences to see if I can get a little stronger of an understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think "arange" is from Numpy.  You need to use "xrange" if you want the built in Python function.  If you want the Numpy "arange", then you will need to import Numpy.  Based on your snip of code, you are using Numpy so add:

`from numpy import *`

Comment: I'll have to look up what exactly Numpy is, but I tried putting in xrange in place of arange and got: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'xrange' and 'xrange'

Comment: Are you using matplotlib or scipy?

Comment: Matplotlib rings a bell but I'm honestly not sure. Our class gave us the canopy package to download and I just open up an editor through it. I tried adding your snip of code and it's still giving me the TypeError.